# Crepes sliding off crepe maker base

Tags: crepe

I recently made crepes with a crepe maker like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WW46QA). The first half of the recipe worked perfectly. Then, every time I dipped the base into the batter, when I removed it, the half cooked crepe would slide off into the pan of wet batter. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the first half of the recipe worked fine, it sounds like your crepe maker might be losing heat. Does your model have a ready indicator like the one you linked to? Either way, try giving the crepe maker a minute or two to reheat in the middle of your cooking.

Comment: Yes! the indicator showed that the machine was hot & ready! Next time, I'll let it warm for a while even after the indicator showing that it's reheating is off. Thanks!

Comment: I've made it into an answer, so if that works the next time you make crepes feel free to choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first half of the recipe worked fine, it sounds like your crepe maker might be losing heat. Try giving the crepe maker a minute or two to reheat in the middle of your cooking.

Don't necessarily trust the ready indicator either. An infrared thermometer would help, but you can also drop a few drops of water on the grill. If the water quickly sizzles and evaporates, it should be ready.